# Vmware shared folder not working in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, virtualization, vmware

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit in Vmware workstation 10 but the shared folder is not working in Ubuntu 13.10,while it works perfectly in Ubuntu 13.04.

I reinstalled Vmware tools several times but it doesn't work.

All other features like drag and drop is working.

Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: Not much help in this comment, but I use vmware workstation 9 and ubuntu 13.10 without issues.  Drag/drop and shared folders all work fine.  Maybe a patch/update for Workstation is needed?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded 13.04 to 13.10 and was having the same "can't access shared folders" problem.

## Edit:

Found the solution [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184195).
I had actually previously tried this, but in my previous attempts I was installing Vmware tools 9.2 from a previous version of Vmware.

I re-untarred the Vmware tools from the mounted CD `Player` | `Manage` | `Re-install VMWare Tools...` applied the patch, and ran the installer script in my case: `~/vmware-tools-distrib/vmware-install.pl`.
I had to modify the `fix.sh` file in the link to point to my paths but once I did that, shared folders started working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install open-vm-tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
   ```
2. Create mount point for shared folders

   ```
   mkdir /media/SharedFolder
   ```
3. Go to the scripts services directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/init.d
   ```
4. Create script to load at the boot time (if you prefer you can use `nano` instead of `vim`):

   ```
   sudo vim mountshfolder
   #!/bin/bash
   # load vmhgfs kernel module
   modprobe vmhgfs
   # mount vmware share folder
   mount -t vmhgfs .host:/<share_folder_name> /media/SharedFolder
   exit
   ```
5. Give executable permission to the script:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x mountshfolder
   ```
6. Set the script to be execute for all runlevels:

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d mountshfolder defaults
   ```

That's all, now at the boot time, your VMware shared folder will be mounted in `/media/SharedFolder`